# Primefaces Component - colorPicker: Popup does not render,

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have integrated two Primefaces "p:colorPicker", an "p:inputTextarea" and two "p:commandButton" in my JBoss webapp. The idea is to select a color and update the link provided in the "p:inputTextarea" via ajax after click on the "p:commandButton" "Update Url" (please find the code below).

This is my fist attempt to integrate Primefaces into my webapp (via Maven). On running the app I can see that the "p:inputTextarea" and the two "p:commandButtons" are rendered properly. I can resize the "p:inputTextarea" and on click on the "Update Url" the "p:inputTextarea" is refreshed. So that I assume that the integration of Primefaces works.

The issue I have is with the "p:colorPicker":
I can see that the Primefaces-style of the buttons, but the colorPicker popup is not dislplayed and therefor I can't choose any color. In this case I am using the default mode. When I tried using mode=inline the whole component is not rendered.

Could you please give me some hints on how to solve this issue?
Please let me know if you need further information or code.

Thank you in advance,

Alan

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <h1>Spendenformular bearbeiten</h1>



    <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Hintergrundfarbe:"/>
            <p:colorPicker id="bgColor"
                value="#{spendeFormEditController.bgColor}"
                widgetVar="bgPicker">
            </p:colorPicker>
            <h:outputLabel value="Textfarbe:"/>
            <p:colorPicker id="textColor"
                value="#{spendeFormEditController.textColor}"
                widgetVar="textPicker">
            </p:colorPicker>
            <h:outputLabel value="URL des Formulars:" />
            <p:inputTextarea id="url" rows="6" cols="30" readonly="true"
                value="#{spendeFormEditController.url}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton value="Update URL" update="url" />
        <p:commandButton value="OK"
            action="#{spendeFormEditController.doOk}" ajax="false"/>

    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

And just in case the template I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.comcom/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>My-Aktion</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/screen.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <p>
                Beispielanwendung <b>My-Aktion</b> - Workshop Java EE 7
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">
                [Template content will be inserted here]
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p> (C) 2013 com.fantasma</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</h:body>
```

EDIT:
Hi Xtreme Biker: Thanx a lot for your reply!

I am using Primefaces version 3.5, and Mozlla Firefox 25.0

In the meantime, however, I tried to do some changes on another view of my webapp and I could see that actually PF does not work!

As I told before I am using JBoss with Maven. So I have installed PF via Maven doing the needed changes in pom.xml. As far as I could find out by now the PF .jar has been downloaded into the .m2 file.

And I could find the .jar in Eclipse in: target->my-aktion(=project)->WEB-INF->lib.

There I could find two versions of PF! 3.3 and 3.5 Might there be a conflict? Do I have to check the deployment in JBoss seperately (how can I do it)?

Thank you in advance, Alan

Here is the pom.xml:
    
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.fantasma</groupId>
<artifactId>my-aktion</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Java EE 6 webapp project</name>
<description>A starter Java EE 6 webapp project for use on JBoss AS 7.1 / EAP 6, generated from the jboss-javaee6-webapp archetype</description>

<properties>
    <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following 
        message: -->
    <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered 
        resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- Define the version of JBoss' Java EE 6 APIs and Tools we want 
        to import. -->
    <jboss.bom.version>1.0.0.Final</jboss.bom.version>
    <!-- Alternatively, comment out the above line, and un-comment the 
        line below to use version 1.0.0.M12-redhat-1 which is a release certified 
        to work with JBoss EAP 6. It requires you have access to the JBoss EAP 6 
        maven repository. -->
    <!-- <jboss.bom.version>1.0.0.M12-redhat-1</jboss.bom.version>> -->
</properties>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including 
            a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or 
            a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct 
            versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools stack 
            (you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras 
            tools for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate 
            stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with extras 
            from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. 
        All of them are provided by JBoss AS 7 -->

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided 
        scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
    <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
    <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
        in JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->


    <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes 
        for typesafe criteria queries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Annotation processor that raising compilation errors whenever 
        constraint annotations are incorrectly used. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
    <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and 
        Transactional(JTA) JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the 
        name given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates 
            annotation processors -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to 
                    catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The JBoss AS plugin deploys your war to a local JBoss AS 
            container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package jboss-as:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune 
            it to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
        <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including 
            Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
        <id>default</id>
        <repositories>  
            <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>Primefaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
            in your JBoss AS instance -->
        <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss AS instance, and execute 
            the test, shutting it down when done -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed -->
        <id>arq-jbossas-managed</id>
        <repositories>  
            <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>Primefaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests 
            in a remote JBoss AS instance -->
        <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote -->
        <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
        <repositories>  
            <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>Primefaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories> 
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be 
            used when invoking mvn. -->
        <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization 
            your app will need. -->
        <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 
            'deployments' folder. -->
        <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
        <id>openshift</id>
        <repositories>  
            <repository>
                <id>prime-repo</id>
                <name>Primefaces Maven Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <dependencies>

        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                        <warName>ROOT</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

Comment: Which PF version are you using? Which browser is it?

Comment: Hi Xtreme Biker: Thanx a lot for your reply! I am using Primefaces version 3.5, and Mozlla Firefox 25.0 In the meantime, however, I tried to do some changes on another view of my webapp and I could see that actually PF does not work! As I told before I am using JBoss with Maven. So I have installed PF via Maven doing the needed changes in pom.xml.

Comment: Just check you have the jar into your WEB-INF folder. It should be straight forward to configure it.

Comment: Hi, Xtreme Biker: I have added some further information in the question above as there is not enough space in this section. I could find the PF 3.5 in the WEB-Inf->lib folder of the target-folder of my project, additionally it is listed in the .jar files in the Maven dependencies.

Comment: I don't think you can use `provided` on primefaces `dependency` scope, cause it's not provided by Jboss. you should use compile scope and you should provide specific version to primefaces

Comment: SRy, thanx for the reply! There are two sections in the pom.xml: DependencyManagement; and Dependencies. Do I need an entry in both sections? I have added <version>3.5</version> and changed the scope to <scope>compile</scope> in both entries but it still does not work. Additionally I got a new warning in the pom section dependencies stating: Overriding managed version of 3.5 of primefaces.

Comment: no idea on how to fix this? Any help will be appreciated.