# ColorPicker does not respond

Tags: javascript, html, background-color

Goal:
I would like to select a color through color picker HTML element and immediately after this change I would like to see canvas element in the same color.

The issue: I can select color through the color picker, but my canvas rectangle is not changing the color. All of the questions are focused on more robust solutions (i.e. with JBOSS or jQuery or SpringBoot)

Like here:

- [Bootstrap colorpicker basic example does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857642/bootstrap-colorpicker-basic-example-does-not-work|jQUery)
- [Primefaces Component - colorPicker: Popup does not render,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859440/primefaces-component-colorpicker-popup-does-not-render)

What I tried:

- Read similar questions here
- Different ID names
- Different method name
- Different color in the white CSS class
- Different browser
- The different access method for canvas, see below:

```
function setColorAccordingToColorPicker() {
    var rectangle = getElementById("canvasColorpicker");
    var colorinput = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
    var color = colorinput.value;
    rectangle.fillStyle = color;
    rectangle.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
}
```

None of them helped.

MCVE:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvasColorpicker" class="white"></canvas>
    <input type="color" value="#001A57" onchange="setColorAccordingToColorPicker()" id="colorPicker">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function setColorAccordingToColorPicker() {
    var rectangle = getElementById("canvasColorpicker");
    var colorinput = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
    var color = colorinput.value;
    rectangle.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

CSS

```
.white {
    background-color: #001A57;
}

canvas {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid lighgrey;
}
```

Can someone help and see what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use another way to access the canvas properties : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp

Comment: I tried now (also attached my solution to the question), but it was not successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function setColorAccordingToColorPicker() {
    var rectangle = document.getElementById("canvasColorpicker");
    var colorinput = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
    var color = colorinput.value;
    rectangle.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
.white {
    background-color: #001A57;
}

canvas {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid lighgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvasColorpicker" class="white"></canvas>
    <input type="color" value="#001A57" onchange="setColorAccordingToColorPicker()" id="colorPicker">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

One little change needed:

Change this: `var rectangle = getElementById("canvasColorpicker");`

To: `var rectangle = document.getElementById("canvasColorpicker");`

Comment: nice ! didn't see it !

Comment: I am blind. Thank you!